# Compressing image and text file and attaching to swift mail composer

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Actually I had an image file and text file. I wanted to compress the two files and add as an attachment to swift mail composer. Any Solution? Please help

Comment: For compressing image open this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681990/compress-images-to-reduce-file-size

Comment: @iOS This is not the solution required for me. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

You can zip your files using  this

https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip library

here is sample code added

```
do {
    let filePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file", withExtension: "zip")!
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for:.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    try Zip.unzipFile(filePath, destination: documentsDirectory, overwrite: true, password: "password", progress: { (progress) -> () in
        print(progress)
    }) // Unzip

    let zipFilePath = documentsFolder.appendingPathComponent("archive.zip")
    try Zip.zipFiles([filePath], zipFilePath: zipFilePath, password: "password", progress: { (progress) -> () in
        print(progress)
    }) //Zip

}
catch {
  print("Something went wrong")
}
```

And attach that zip to your mail composer

Hope it is helpful

Comment: The solution is fine if we are fetching the files from a folder right. but I have files in the project itself and an image too. How can it be compressed? Please help

Comment: @Rakesh You can easily do it. you just need to save the files in your document directory for temporary time and you done with zip you can remove from that location.

Comment: It is better to use filesystem as it will reduce load on your memory so there is least chance to memory issues in future

Comment: This pod is only swift 4. Does it work in swift 3? As mentioned in the document it works with swift 4

Comment: @Rakesh I am not sure about it what version of xcode you are using ?